# Android 4.4.2 add a new page

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

understand that the process to create a new page is as follows : drag new app to right of screen until the new page appears however no success it just keeps rotating through my existing pages. can anyone help ?many thanks

Comment: What phone? What launcher? Please provide more details

Comment: A Galaxy Note 2 how do I establish the launcher thanks

Comment: Additional information I currently have 7 screens 1-e pages home pages                  is there a limit

Comment: @DeniseStain Hello Denise, did you try to put some apps in folders on the homescreens? Like all messaging ones in a folder etc. That might save a lot of space.

Comment: Daniel just tried that thanks that is certainly another approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Based on comments)

> I currently have 7 screens 1-e pages home pages is there a limit

Yes. Thats the limit of default samsung launcher (touchwiz). *You cannot add more than 7 pages.* A workaround for this would be to use a third-party after market launcher ([here](https://www.androidpit.com/what-is-the-best-android-launcher) are some examples of android launchers you can use from play store). However, just for future reference, you can follow the methods below besides dragging the app icon to home screen to add a new screen:

- Perform a "zoom out" pinch gesture on home screen which should take you to screens editing mode/page. You can press the `+` button there to add new screen.
- Go to launcher's menu (by pressing the menu key (the key to the left side of *home* button) while you are on homescreen). Then in the menu that appears, select `Edit Page`. This should again bring you to screen management page as above.
- Press and hold a blank area in your home screen. This should also take you to screen editing mode where you can press `+` button to add more screens.

About android launcher:

> Launcher is the name given to the part of the Android user interface
>   that lets users customize the home screen (e.g. the phone's desktop),
>   launch mobile apps, make phone calls, and perform other tasks on
>   Android devices (devices that use the Android mobile operating
>   system).

For more information about android launchers, you can refer [this](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/android_launcher.html) and [this](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-z-what-launcher).

Comment: Jaskaranbir Singh thank you very much for your time and response I've had this phone for a while and I'm only now trying to improve my productivity I will certainly use this forum again

Comment: Your welcome ;) Please mark the answer as solved if it helped you for future references.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a "zoom out" pinch gesture on home screen which should take you to screens editing mode/page. You can press the + button there to add new screen.

Go to launcher's menu (by pressing the menu key (the key to the left side of home button) while you are on homescreen). Then in the menu that appears, select Edit Page. This should again bring you to screen management page as above.

Press and hold a blank area in your home screen. This should also take you to screen editing mode where you can press + button to add more screens.

The NO of Pages you can add is dictated by your launcher . I use touchwiz which is limited to 7 pages . I had already set up 7 pages which is why I was experiencing problems.